# SignalR Hosting on LAN

Tags: signalr

I have a SignalR server that hosts on a computer of which IP is (192.168.0.110)

```
var SignalR = WebApp.Start("http://*/8080");
```

And a client on the same computer connects to the SignalR host.

```
public HubConnection Connection { get; set; }    
Connection = new HubConnection(http://192.168.0.110/signalr/);
```

My problem is that the client can connect to the SignalR host when I run them both in debug mode in VS2015 but they don't when I deploy them to another computer.

Comment: Probably pretty silly question - but have you set up your URLs to be configurable and not hard coded as they are in your example?  If you're deploying the signalr server to another computer, and still trying to hit your localhost, then that could be why you're not getting a response?

Comment: May be you misunderstand my question, As in many samples the serverURI is "http://localhost:8080", But instead of "localhost", I use the computer IP.

Comment: and the IP address of `192.168.0.110` is that your local, or your server?  You stated that running it locally works fine (what is that endpoint address?) but not on server (what is that endpoint address?)  How are you changing the configuration between local and deployed?  That is what's unclear to me in your question

Comment: Sorry for my English, server app and client app are run on the same computer. I still can connect to server from other computer running client app.

Comment: Problem solved, I have to enable app to access the IP loopback by using Windows Loopback Exemption Manager. This is done by VS while running in debug mode